# onDeviceReady() works but document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady(), false); fails. Why?

Tags: javascript, html, cordova

Below is my script:

```
<script>
var candata = {cantitle:"", candetail:"", imagesource:"", canlat:"", canlon:""};
    var cantemplate = '<input type="text" name="cantitle" id="cantitle" value="{{cantitle}}" placeholder="can Title"/><textarea cols="40" rows="8" name="candetail" id="candetail" placeholder="can Detail">{{candetail}}</textarea><input id="addphoto" type="button" data-icon="plus" value="Add a Photo" /><img id="canimage" src="{{imagesource}}" /><div id="map">Map Placeholder</div><input id="savecan" type="button" data-theme="a" value="Save can" />';

    $(document).on("pageinit", function(){
        $("#newcan").on("pagecreate", function(){
            var html = Mustache.to_html(cantemplate);
            $("#candetailcontent").html(html);
        });
    });

function init() {
        document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady(), false);
    }

    function onDeviceReady() {
        alert('Ready');  //Not being called
        var networkstate = navigator.network.connection.type;
        if(networkstate="none"){
            $("#offline").css("visibility", "visible");
        }
    }
</script>
```

The alert in onDeviceReady() fires however if I change the document's addEventListener to `document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);` the alert won't fire. Why?

**EDIT**

Full code: Why is my onDeviceReady not firing?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="format-detection" content="telephone-no">
    <meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, width=device-width, height=device-height, target-densitydpi=device-dpi">
    <title>Our Application</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/themes/default/jquery.mobile-1.3.2.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css">
    <script src="js/jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="js/jquery.mobile-1.3.2.min.js"></script>
    <script src="cordova.ios.js"></script>
    <script src="js/mustache.js"></script>
    <script>
    var candata = {cantitle:"", candetail:"", imagesource:"", canlat:"", canlon:""};
        var cantemplate = '<input type="text" name="cantitle" id="cantitle" value="{{cantitle}}" placeholder="can Title"/><textarea cols="40" rows="8" name="candetail" id="candetail" placeholder="can Detail">{{candetail}}</textarea><input id="addphoto" type="button" data-icon="plus" value="Add a Photo" /><img id="canimage" src="{{imagesource}}" /><div id="map">Map Placeholder</div><input id="savecan" type="button" data-theme="a" value="Save can" />';

        $(document).on("pageinit", function(){
            $("#newcan").on("pagecreate", function(){
                var html = Mustache.to_html(cantemplate);
                $("#candetailcontent").html(html);
            });
        });

    function init() {
            document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);
        }

        function onDeviceReady() {
            alert('Ready');  //Not being called
            var networkstate = navigator.network.connection.type;
            if(networkstate="none"){
                $("#offline").css("visibility", "visible");
            }
        }
    </script>
    </head>
    <body onload="init()">
<div data-role="page" id="main">
      <div data-role="header" class="logo"> <img src="img/logo.png" /> </div>
      <div data-role="content">
    <ul id="canlist" data-role="listview">
        </ul>
    <a href="#newcan" data-role="button" data-icon="plus">New can</a> </div>
      <div data-role="footer" data-theme="c">
    <h2 class="offline">Offline Mode</h2>
  </div>
    </div>
<div data-role="page" id="newcan">
      <div data-role="header" class="logo"> <img src="img/logo.png" /> </div>
      <div id="candetailcontent" data-role="content"> </div>
      <div data-role="footer" data-theme="c">
    <p>Snapcan!</p>
  </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: First one invokes the function then and there as it is evaluated while setting up the callback for the handler, second one where it doesn't alert is the correct way of doing, and you should focus on the issue with deviceready event not firing...

Comment: Ahh thanks. Any idea why the onDeviceReady isn't firing?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your first function declaration:

`function init() {
        document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady(), false);
    }`

by virtue of the parentheses following onDeviceReady, *calls* the function and evaluates the return value as a parameter to addEventListener, whereas the second version:

```
document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);
```

**omits** the parentheses, and is thus a *reference* to the function *to be called*.